# Creating a backup of 'this'

Tags: javascript, backup, this

In javascript, I have an object (think of it as a shape), that can be put in edit mode and edited, or a not editable mode.  When editable mode, I want to have a cancel button that cancels all edits and returns the shape back to its original form.  I was hoping to use something like the following, but assigning things to 'this' doesn't work.  What would the best way to do this be?  I would prefer not to use external objects to store backups, because there could be many shapes and sorting out which backup corresponds to what adds code that is not as nicely packaged.

```
Shape.prototype.edit = function() {
    this.backup = this;
    ...
}
Shape.prototype.cancelEdit = function() {
    this = this.backup;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `Shape` should contain properties object, for example `this.properties`. In that object you should store all information about shape (it will be something like shape's model, only data, without any methods, or other internal class data). And in backup function you should backup only properties, not all shape's object.

(I'm a non native english speaker, feel free to correct my message if need)

Comment: Are you saying `this.properties` returns an object with all the non-function properties?  Because it does not for me.

Comment: @roboguy222 I create a fiddle, check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/vCTze/ If it is not for you, tell me why, may be I can to find another solution.

Comment: Oh, so you stored everything within the object in another object called properties.  I guess that works, but it would be nice to not have to type properties every time.

Comment: @roboguy222 I prefer this way, because it is similar to [backbone's model](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes) (everything stored in the `atrributes` object).

Answer (score 0):

You could implement something like this, where you go through each key in the object and if it's a property and not a function then store in a backup array.

```
var backup ;

function backup()
{
    backup = [];
    for(var key in this) {
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof this[key] !== 'function') {
            backup[key] = this[key];
        }
    }
}

function restore()
{
    for(var key in backup) {
        this[key] = backup[key];
    }
}
```